# jquery selector - exclude first and second

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to exclude first and second element from jquery selector. I tried this:

```
$('p:not(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(2))')
```

But this only excludes the first element... Thanks

Comment: This should work if your first and second child are, in fact, `p` elements. Questions like this do best when the working markup is provided.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This jQuery sequence uses [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to discard the first two elements from the `$('p')` selector:

```
$('p').slice(2).
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zWV7Z/

Note that this is *not* the same as `nth-child` - the exclusion is based on the whole set of elements found in the first selector, and not on their relative position in the DOM.

Comment: I prefer this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Simply:

```
$('p:gt(1)')
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/NtFYq/1/

As Alnitak has pointed out in the comment, if performance is a concern, you can use his solution of `slice`

Thanks a lot @Alnitak for pointing that out :)

Comment: yes, that works, but will be less efficient than `.slice()` because the pseudo-selector will prevent use of the native `querySelectorAll()` function.

Comment: yeah, it's better to avoid invoking the sizzle selector parser if you can.

Comment: incorrectly...  I've used `.slice()` which _does_ return a jQuery selector.

Comment: Conciseness/simplicity trumps efficiency in most cases.  This is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $('p').not(":nth-child(1)").not(":nth-child(2)")
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmb78/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('p:not(:nth-child(1)),p:not(:nth-child(2))')
```

Reference:
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation

from that reference:
"The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a ***simple selector*** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument...."

Comment: This is relevant to CSS, but not to jQuery; jQuery's version of the `:not()` selector allows a comma-separated list of any arbitrarily complicated selector, and the only reason to write a CSS-valid version in a jQuery string is for performance (see the comments on one of the other answers about `querySelectorAll()`). I'm going to post a question detailing this difference soon...

Comment: If you really did want to write a CSS-valid version, it should be `p:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2))`, not `p:not(:nth-child(1)),p:not(:nth-child(2))`. Again, this will be covered in my post.

Comment: @BoltClock: I see, the selector needs to produce the negation of the union [1st, 2nd] not the union of the negation of each [1st], and [2nd], because the latter would just include all children since [1st] and [2nd] are mutually exclussive. Thanks.

Comment: As promised... [What's the difference in the :not() selector between jQuery and CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').not($('p').eq(0), $('p').eq(1))
```