# css selectors all elements inside a certain div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to retrieve ALL input type checkbox 
that are not inside a div that has a class that starts with 'xyz_'

How do I write a css selector for the above?

Comment: *Not* inside a div with a class that starts with `xyz_`? That won't be easy.

Answer (score 3):

use `div:not([class^="xyz_"]) input[type="checkbox"]{ ... }`

see working example http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3zY/

Comment: Your CSS will not work if `<input>` is not inside any `<div>`

Comment: According to the question, targeted `<input>` can be not necessary inside some `<div>`, so `<html><body><input type="checkbox"/></body></html>` is a valid case not covered by your selector.

Comment: @spatar there is no problem if we use input elements inside div. This fiddle is based on your solution http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3zY/1/ but it doesn't worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
*:not(div[class^="xyz_"]) input[type="checkbox"] { ... }
```

Comment: Note that this will currently only work in jQuery, and is a very fragile solution (like I commented above, it's not trivial even if you use `:not()`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css

Comment: @BoltClock, absolutely. I still don't use those fancy selectors much in regular practice :)