# select element that does not contain a string within an attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

let's say that I have some

```
<TR style = "background-color : red ;">
```

and some

```
<TR>
```

(to be noted that the spaces next to the colon and to the semicolon are intentional, because the page I am dealing with is written in that way)

now, this:

```
$('.detailtable tr:not([style~="darkgray"])')
```

works perfectly. But [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) it says:

> [name!="value"] cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").not('[name="value"]') instead

so I was wondering: is my expression the best one or something like:

```
$('.detailtable tr').not('[style~="darkgray"]') // this doesn't work!
```

is better performing? And what is the correct way of writing this last expression?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.detailtable tr').not('[style~="darkgray"]') ` should work the same. If you are worried about performance, test it: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: as I wrote in the comment, $('.detailtable tr').not('[style~="darkgray"]') doesn't work...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you really want to "select element that **does not contain a string within an attribute**", you should use `*=` instead of `~=`, like so:

```
$('.detailtable tr').not('[style*="darkgray"]');
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSGs7/).

---

And no, using `.not` is probably not faster. `querySelectorAll` should be able to parse that selector as is.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSGs7/1/).

---

**Edit:** If you care about IE8 that much, then using the `.not` method instead of the `:not` selector will give you a small performance boost. The reason for this is very simple: IE8 does support attribute selectors, but not the negation selector.

Comment: Yes, it'll work with `querySelectorAll()` because it's a valid CSS selector. See also: [What is the difference in the :not() selector between jQuery and CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css) (I was going to write a small section about how people should stop caring about performance, but I figured people out there probably already care too much about performance to care to read that, so I didn't care to write it...)

Comment: @BoltClock - of course there are differences between the native `:not` selector and jQuery's beefed up `:not`. However, in this case, it's safe to assume that the native implementation will handle it just fine.

Comment: @BoltClock - I care very much about performance, but I would gladly hear your opinion. Care to share? I'd read it even if it were small-novel-book length...

Comment: Well, I tend to only worry about performance if performance is critical. I don't try to optimize or agonize over every single line of code until and unless a bottleneck is found. That said it's always good practice to write selectors that can take advantage of `querySelectorAll()` as much as possible, but deliberately making things overly complicated just to save milliseconds is going overboard in my book...

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks for sharing your thoughts, and I wholeheartedly agree. Legibility definitely comes before a minor speed boost. However, in this case, I think using `.not` is even more legible (read: scan-able), since it's not just one single long string.

Comment: @JosephSilber: thanks, but now I'm curious: what's the difference between `~=` and `*=`?

From jQuery documentation:
`[name~="value"]
Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value 
containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

[name*="value"]
Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value 
containing the given substring.`

so? `~=` does an exact match while `*=` does not?

Comment: @Pierpaolo - given the following element: `<img class="one two three">`, using `[class~=two]` will match, whereas with `<img class="twofold">` it won't match. `[name*=two]` will match in both cases.

Comment: @JosephSilber OK, precisely as I've guessed, then. Thanks
*Edit*: as I said in the question text: it does not work!

Comment: **Second attempt:** although it works with jQuery 1.7.2, with version 1.6.4 (the version I am currently using) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

[I'd suggest you take a look at this.](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck)

Interestingly enough, pseudo selectors (like ":not") tend to actually be slower than using a function next to the initial selector.  In fact... they're apparently "twice as slow".

I quote:

1. `$("#id p");`
2. `$("#id").find("p");`

> Would it surprise you to learn that
>   the second way can be more than twice as fast as the first? Knowing
>   which selectors outperform others (and why) is a pretty key building
>   block in making sure your code runs well and doesn’t frustrate your
>   users waiting for things to happen.

I'd go with `.not` my friend!

Comment: According to http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2, pseudo-selectors are the slowest of all selectors.  I haven't found any evidence that says they are faster than chaining a jQuery function afterwards.  Then again, just because I haven't found said evidence doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), what you currently use should work perfectly fine even with `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Maybe you can test if it works as expected.

Comment: `:not()` was added to the draft many years ago, and jQuery picked up on it soon enough...

Comment: @BoltClock But the [selectors table](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) mentions `3` in `First defined in CSS level` column for the Negation Pseudo Class. Hence I thought this was a recent addition to the selectors list. 

Please provide any references to confirm that this was picked up by jQuery earlier.

I'll wait for you response before editing.

Comment: CSS3 was only made a recommendation recently, but it was in draft for more than 10 years and `:not()` has been around for just as long (go to the spec page and keep clicking on "Previous version"). jQuery shipped with `:not()` in its first major stable release - it says "version added: 1.0" in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector).