# Can I style a listview depending on number of contained list items using CSS only?

Tags: css, list, border

On my page I have a number of `listviews`.

Some contain a single list item, some contain more than one item. I'm looking for a way to set top/bottom borders depending on number of list items in a CSS only way.

So in a single item list, borders should be:

```
listitem > border-top & border-bottom
```

Two item lists

```
listitem > border-top
listitem > border-top & border-bottom
```

Three+ item list

```
listitem > border-top
listitem > border-top & border-bottom
listitem > border-bottom
```

Right now I have this CSS

```
.inputList li:not( .inputList li:first-child, .inputList li:last-child) {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    }
.inputList li:first-child {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    }
.inputList li:last-child {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    }
```

But this doesn't take me very far and I'm using `not:` which I would rather try to avoid (for lack of IE support)

Any idea if this is at all possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `:not()` syntax is invalid CSS but works in jQuery. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering what I was doing...

Comment: @BoltClock: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/not.html

Comment: although I'm not sure about support - http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/, still I trust quirksmode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
.inputList li:first-child {
   border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.inputList li {
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

with that you will always have a border on top and a border on the bottom and in between.

Comment: Don't you just need one border in between? In your two list example you will have double borders after the first li. Isn't that what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/CBGcE/

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I must be having another style setting false borders. Thanks for help!