# Pseudo-class inside :not

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use a pseudo class inside of a :not tag?

Example:

```
li:not(.inner:hover):hover { // Code }

<li>
   <div class="inner"></div>
</li>
```

I am trying to cancel out the effect of the parent hover, when I hover an inner item, without using javascript.

The expected result for above code is when you hover the li, but not the inner div, the li get's a hover effect. But only if you're not hovering the .inner.

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/eTV86/
What I want is, when the .inner turns black, the li turns back to red.

Comment: Do you have some representative HTML that we could experiment with? And could you explain *exactly* what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am confused ... Can you show what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: I think you should mimic the same effect on the hover with CSS instead of using `:not` ... just re-declare it

Comment: Updated with more information

Comment: Went with the jQuery ::parent selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you're using both a class and a pseudo-class, which is invalid:

```
li:not(.inner:hover):hover
```

Even if you change it to something that's valid (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css/10711731#10711731)):

```
li:not(.inner):hover, li:not(:hover):hover
```

The first selector will always match your `li` on hover, and the second selector won't ever match anything. It will never match your `div.inner` because you're attaching the `:not()` to the `li`.

Lastly, if you want to change the `li` when `.inner` gets a hover, that's not possible with current CSS selectors. You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: So I can't tell if the child's hover is active inside a :not?

Comment: You can't, because `:not()` only looks at whatever element you attach it to, not its children. And since there's still no parent selector, you can't do it with CSS currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple css instead pseudo class

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href = "#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

​
​
CSS

```
ul li a{ color:black}
ul li a:hover { color:red }
ul li.active a:hover { color:black /*re use the same properties which is there in default style viz ul li a{} */}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mKQas/2/

Comment: I don't understand, how does this cancel out the hover of li, if you mouse over the <a>?