# CSS [ Negate the parent element ]

Tags: css

Can I do the following:

```
.content:not([class="no-touch"]) {

    .content-index-container {

        .chr-selector {

            select {
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when the `no-touch` class in not in the `content` class, but the other way around.

I know that my CSS won't work because it's wrong, but how can I achieve what I'm trying to do: style the content but ignore the styling if the content it's not within the `touch` class? (Modernizr appends the class to the HTML if touch devices are detected.)

Comment: Or maybe something like this : `:not(.no-touch > .content)` ?

Comment: i think the easiest option is to work with two separate stylesheet, if that is possible in the system you work with.
Or you could overwrite one style with the other, but then you'll have to write those stylerules twice.
Or if you like the syntax you proposed, you could try LESS or SASS.

Comment: @besluitloos ~ I am using LESS (:

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with LESS, But I thought i recognized the format... As you prefer to avoid JS (your comment below), I would recommend write and overwrite your styles with the no-touch class, or use two different stylesheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reverse your thinking and modify the no-touch child instead....

```
select { margin-top: 5px; }
.content.no-touch .content-index-container .chr-selector select {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

or

```
select { margin-top: 5px; }
.content.no-touch select {  margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I am afraid not. Javascript is your friend or add extra classes to your markup.

Comment: I was thinking the same .... god damn it ... so I cannot use the `:not()` css selector like this ... ?

Comment: @Roland: Nope, you can't. You can, however, use it in that manner in a JavaScript library like jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css

Comment: I kind of prefer avoiding JS as much as possible (: