# CSS select element which does not follow element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select all P's which do not follow a H3 or a P so:

```
<img>

<p> this is selected</p>

<p> this is not</p>

<p> this is not</p>

<span>

<p> this is selected</p>

<h3>

<p> this is not</p>
```

I tried

```
p + :not(h3, p) and :not(h3, p) + p
```

but they do not work

what is the solution? Please help

Comment: You would be better off by not using a single selector for this. A big portion of browsers would not support such an advanced selector so my advice is to group and `<h3>` and `<p>` elements into `<section>` tags and then apply a class to them. This way you can target elements before and after the block.

Comment: I only want to text indent the selected elements, its more of a progressive enhancement then a site breaking thing. If it was any properties, I would have done something different.

Comment: @Ozzy, it is then simpler (and more cross-browser) to set first the text indent on `p` in general, then override it with a rule that applies to `p` elements that follow certain elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can express that, as css selector, this way:

`*:not(h3):not(p) + p`

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/72b1c/1)

Comment: It's not necessary, I added it to better express what the selector does.

Comment: As a quick aside, one of the solutions from the question, `:not(h3, p) + p` will work in jQuery, and is tentatively specced into Selectors 4, but won't work in browsers that currently implement Selectors 3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css And of course, there's also the potential issue of browser support.

Comment: If you need to select the `p` if it's the first child, just add that to the selector so you have both of them: `p:first-child, :not(h3):not(p) + p`.

Answer (score -1):

```
:not(h3):not(p) + p {
    ...
}
```

​

Comment: Nelson was first.  See his answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use classes like this...

```
<img>
<p class="sel"> this is selected</p>
<p> this is not</p>
<p> this is not</p>
<span>
<p class="sel"> this is selected</p>
<h3>
<p> this is not</p>
```

Then in your CSS you can modify them with...

```
.sel {
   /* Styling here */
}
```