# CSS select br not followed by br

Tags: css

I want to select `br` elements that are not followed by another `br`.

For example.

```
<br>sometext<br>adsf
```

I want to select both of these elements.

```
<br><br>sometext<br><br>adsf
```

I only want to select 2 br element, not 4.

I've seen this question but I don't understand how it works.

[CSS select element which does not follow element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212909/css-select-element-which-does-not-follow-element)

Comment: Why do you want to select `<br>` tags? You can't do anything with them.

Comment: `:not(br) + br` will do it. Isn't that apparent from the examples on that other question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS select element which does not follow element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212909/css-select-element-which-does-not-follow-element)

Comment: @Jon Won't this select br-tags which are not following another br tag? (In the example above it'd select the first br-tag of two, but it should be last of two.)

Comment: @Jon an example would be appreciated, doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JezenThomas you can modify br elements if you set their `content: " "` like this.

Comment: @Harry: Indeed. After looking at it more carefully, the problem here is that the text between the `<br>` tags does not count for anything. So `:not(br) + br` does not select anything because every `<br>` that follows *something* in fact follows a `<br>`. If you put the text inside `<span>`s you will see that the selector does apply.

Comment: @Harry: However, it still won't select `<br>` not *followed* by `<br>` -- CSS selectors in general don't "look forward".

Answer (score 1):

Use two selectors, one which adds a style to *all* `br` tags and one which removes that style for `br+br`.

```
br { /* add the style */ }
br+br {  /* take it away again, or change it to 'inherit' */ }
```