# CSS with :not selector working when placed inside as jquery selector, not with pure CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference in the :not() selector between jQuery and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css)

How to write CSS selector for a **class** `'ui-content'`. But it should not be child of a **id** `'ui-container'`?

I tried with following selector in CSS.

```
.ui-content:not(#ui-container > .ui-content) {
    //styles goes here
}
```

But it does work in jquery like `$('.ui-content:not(#ui-container > .ui-content)')`, but not in pure CSS.

How to correct this CSS selector?

Does all selectors working with jquery doesn't work with pure CSS selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple:

```
:not(#ui-container) > .ui-content{
   // style
 }
```

You just need to make sure that there are no other classes that can comply to not being #ui-container and still be .ui-content's direct parent.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The selectors are working nice.

Comment: This is explained in the duplicate question which I have linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use logic like this in CSS if you want to support IE8 or lower as you are essentially going up the DOM to look at a parent element which CSS cannot do.

The alternative is to apply a global style to all `.ui-content` elements, and then use a more specific selector to override that style for elements inside the container, eg `#ui-container .ui-content`. Try this:

```css
.ui-content {
    color: #C00;    /* Dark red */
}

#ui-container .ui-content {
    color: #CCC;    /* Grey */
}
```

Comment: @JustinJohn That must be nice. I envy you :)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with IE8 support.

Comment: It does in the sense that the `:not` selector wont work in anything <IE9

Comment: My point is that your first sentence doesn't make any sense. If CSS as a language doesn't support something in the first place, how is IE8 support relevant?