# How can I add more than one not to a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS:

```
#content-button-panel ul li a.folder span {
  cursor: default;
}
#content-button-panel ul li a:not(.folder) span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
<a class="title-coffee"><span>Overview</span></a>
```

How can I make it so the HTML (with class of title-xxxxxxx) has a cursor of default?  Note I need this to work with title-coffee or any class starting with title-

Comment: Why not add a second class to those links and target that instead?

Comment: So you want `a.folder span` and `a.title-xxxxxxx span` to have a default cursor, and everything else to be pointer?

Comment: @BoltClock - Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negation with CSS can be done <strike>2 ways</strike> 1 way:

<strike>input:not(.classA, .classB) /* personally, I've never seen this work */</strike>

or

```
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"])
```

Typically, I would recommend simply using a 3rd class instead of using `:not`.  But in the case of `input` elements where some elements look better with the browser's default styling, writing out an inclusive selector to catch every single type I *do* want to style is considerably longer than writing out a negation selector for the types I *don't* want, I'll go for the shorter selector.

`:not` can be chained like any other simple selector or pseudo-class

```
a[class^="title-"]:not(.folder)
```

Comment: It *cannot* be done the first way in Selectors level 3; only the second (by chaining multiple negations). You may have either seen its use in jQuery (which implements `:not()` very differently; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css)), or seen it in [this article](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector). However, the article is outdated and wrong; it only worked in Firefox 3 due to a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you not just add new CSS classes like this:

```
.cursor {
    cursor: default;
}
.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And then you use each class specifically where needed like:

```
<a class="coffee cursor"><span>Overview</span></a>
<a class="folder pointer"><span>Pointer</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the many [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors). This one selects all a elements whose class attribute begins with "title-"

```
 a[class^="title-"]
```

In your case you'd use it like this:

```
#content-button-panel ul li a.folder span,
#content-button-panel ul li a[class^="title-"] span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I like this but can I combine this with not(.folder) In my case it's the other way around from yours. I want the class that starts with title- to be default.

Comment: Thanks but in my question what I need is for everything to be default except title- and the links with a class of folder. Sorry if the question is confusing.

Comment: No problem. Ok - does this do it? The `cursor: pointer` rule is applied to only those two. Others are left with `cursor: default`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.  I would rather use ID's on each object and target them specifically as needed.  In cases you are targeting a class, it makes it harder to specify specific items which is why I recommend this method.

CSS:

```
.defaultCursor {
   cursor: default;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="ThisItemsID" ><span>Overview</span></a>
```

JS Code (wherever you need to apply the cursor, as needed):

```
$("#ThisItemsID").addClass('defaultCursor');
```

Comment: This won't work, cause specificity of your selector is much lower than those in the question.