# CSS :not() selector specifying previous element

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is a pretty simple question that I can't quite get my head around.

I have a series of divs like this:

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>

<h2>Heading 2</h2>

<p>Paragraph text</p>

<h2>Heading 3</h2>

<p>Paragraph text</p>
```

In CSS I can target h2 tags that follow from h1 tags with: `h1+h2{}`, however I can't seem to use `:not()` in this way. For example, I'd like to use:

```
#text h2:not(h1+h2){
    margin-top:3em;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Am I doing some sort of stupid syntax error or is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [mentioned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251393/css3-not-selector-to-test-parents-class/14251700#14251700), the CSS `:not()` selector doesn't allow combinators inside it, so indeed, it's a syntax error.

In this case, because of the way the `+` combinator works, you *should* be able to simply move `+ h2` out of the `:not()` and remove the `h2` before it, like so:

```css
#text :not(h1) + h2 {
    margin-top: 3em;
}
```

In case `h2` will ever be the first child (which, given your sample, it shouldn't be), and you want to match that, you need to extend the selector a bit:

```css
#text h2:first-child, #text :not(h1) + h2 {
    margin-top: 3em;
}
```

Failing either of those two methods, however, you can always use the good ol' override, [as Joseph Silber demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313158/css-not-selector-specifying-previous-element/14313177#14313177).

Comment: @Joseph Silber: That's not necessary. It's a good alternative! :)

Comment: @Joseph Silber: I should probably make it a point to do that with all my answers since I'm not happy with how the highlighting works either. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Jascination: Glad I helped. You may want to look at my answer to your previous question if you haven't already :)

Answer (score 3):

The CSS `not` pseudo selector does not allow complex selectors. There's nothing you can do about it.

To get the functionality you want, you'll have to override it:

```css
#text h2 {
    margin-top:3em;
}

#text h1 + h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah that's what I currently have done, I thought a more elegant solution would be to condense it into 1 rule instead of 2 but guess it can't be done.