# CSS Select all descendants but not children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am looking for a CSS selector that selects all elements of a certain type (for example all DIV tags), that are *descendants* of the element with the class `parent`, but are NOT *children* of that element.

For example:

```
<div class="parent">

     <div>NOT THIS
          <div>THIS</div>
     </div>

     <div>NOT THIS</div>
     <div>NOT THIS</div>

     <div>NOT THIS
          <div>THIS</div>
          <div>THIS<div>THIS</div></div>
     </div>

</div>
```

I found [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251393/css3-not-selector-to-test-parents-class), which doesn't work in my case, since all elements are descendants of the class `parent`, so this code does not work:

```
 .parent:not(.parent) > div {
     background-color: red;
 }
```

I am wondering if this is possible with the CSS selectors available. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the child selector with the descendant selector for that.

First of you want to select any element that is a child of parent by using `.parent > *`. Then you want to add the descendant selector to select the specific elementtype (`div` in your case).

```css
.parent > * div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div>NOT THIS
    <div>THIS</div>
  </div>

  <div>NOT THIS</div>
  <div>NOT THIS</div>

  <div>NOT THIS
    <div>THIS</div>
    <div>THIS
      <div>THIS</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Will accept as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, there is an alternative approach which I believe is what you intended with your non-working selector:

```css
div {
  color: hsl(0deg 90% 60% / 0.5);
}

/* selects all <div> elements which are not the children of the
   .parent: */
.parent div:not(.parent>*) {
  color: hsl(120deg 90% 40% / 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div>NOT THIS
    <div>THIS</div>
  </div>

  <div>NOT THIS</div>
  <div>NOT THIS</div>

  <div>NOT THIS
    <div>THIS</div>
    <div>THIS
      <div>THIS</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

References:

- [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).