# jQuery select elements only if they aren't nested within like elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Assuming the following:

```
<div class="a"> <!-- select -->
  <div class="b">
    <div class="a"> <!-- skip -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="b">
   <div class="a"> <!-- select -->
     <div class="b">
        <div class="a"> <!-- skip -->

        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="a"> <!-- select -->

</div>
```

How do I only select the outermost $('.a') elements?

Edit: A helpful [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7E7Mk/), in this example, only 'a' should be selected, not 'a!'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where filter methods come in handy:

```
$('.a').not('.a .a');
```

This excludes any `.a` that is nested within another `.a` so you only get the outermost ones, regardless of whether the outermost ones are themselves nested within other elements.

Comment: Perfect! Don't know why I couldn't wrap my head around this. Very simple. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try using the jQuery [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$('.a:not(.a .a)')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7E7Mk/1/

Comment: Thanks brutha, this is correct, just different syntax than @BoltClock's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var a = $('.a'), not = a.find('.a');
a.not(not);
```

[selector profiling](http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-jquery-object-filter)

Comment: Why is it that the concatenated filter performs so poorly?

Comment: @wentz__: Probably because jQuery has to parse the selector, realize that it's not valid CSS (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css), and parse it some more and turn it into a filter. This is why I use the filter method instead if I know I can't do it with a proper CSS selector - because the selector eventually gets converted into a method call anyway.