# Parse error with validation

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, w3c-validation

I was trying to validate my css and this bit of code gave me an error in the css validator, was just wondering what i might be doing wrong here, the error is:

```
select   Parse Error [inp_submit]
select   Parse Error select) { padding-top: 3px; }
```

CSS Code below:

```
content form :not(#inp_submit, select) {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

If you have any suggestions as to what might be going wrong please let me know, thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, [unlike in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css), `:not()` doesn't accept a comma-separated list of selectors. The parse error is probably a result of the validator trying to split the entire selector by that comma, which obviously won't work.

For your CSS to work you need to chain two `:not()` selectors instead:

```
content form :not(#inp_submit):not(select) {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

(Also, just as a sanity check, are you sure your `content` selector is correct? It's a valid type selector, but there is no `content` element in HTML.)

Comment: Yeah haha, i worked it out from the link above but since you have answered my question correctly, i will accept this answer!

Comment: @c.had1990: Always better to have an answered question than one that's left hanging :)