# Logical AND for CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a quite interesting problem here.
I want to target elements that match two conditions at the same time, but I can not find the way

```
<div class='redLink'>
    <!-- ... ... ... -->
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
    <!-- ... ... ... -->
</div>


<div>
    <!-- ... ... ... -->
        <a href='#' class='redLink'>Link</a>
    <!-- ... ... ... -->
</div>
```

---

My ideal CSS would be

```
[*:not(.redLink) a] AND [* a:not(.redLink)] {
    color:green; 
    /* i.e., color NOT red */
}
```

However, the operand `,` is just an `OR` (and, when it doesn't match one condition, it matches the other...!).
And the only `AND` I can find is the logical concatenation `div#myDivId.someClass`, though what I would like is something like `[div#myDiv a].[div.someClass a]`

My goal is to target ONLY those anchors `<a/>` that don't have the class `.redLink` and have no parents with the `.redLink` class eiher.

And, very important, the only thing I want to target is the final anchor, not the whole div or the whole `element.redLink`...

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve this using a CSS selector with a single rule. Currently you can only target `a` elements without the class using `a:not(.redLink)`.

It is not possible to target `a` elements that do not have any `.redLink` ancestors, because the `:not()` pseudo-class doesn't accept combinators (otherwise you would do `a:not(.redLink a)`). A selector like `:not(.redLink) a` wouldn't work either, because that targets `a` elements with at least one ancestor without the class, which is not the same as `a` elements that have *no ancestors with the class*.

For example if your structure looked like this:

```
<div class='redLink'>
    <p>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

That `p` doesn't have the class, so `:not(.redLink) a` would match.

If you happen to have the option of using jQuery, though, `$('a:not(.redLink, .redLink a)')` will work, because [`:not()` is much more permissive in jQuery than in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css).

If you need to do this using CSS only, the easiest solution is to make all `a` elements green, then override it:

```
a {
    color: green;
}

a.redLink, .redLink a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Wow, you really rocked here. My final goal was to use it with jQuery, so you solved my problem straight away. And, if I understand right, there is no way to achieve so using only CSS3, maybe if we wait for CSS4...

Comment: About your second (pure-CSS) solution, it works and I had thought of it, but doesn't satisfy my needs. The actual problem is to target inputs on a form that have `.noValidateField` themselves or their parent. But generally I want to validate, so, again, for your second solution, I would need to add the class `.yesValidate` to all all elements that I want to check, quite stupid I guess. Am I explaining myself correctly? (sorry for double-comment, but is clearer this way)

Comment: @Nico: My specialty lies in selectors :) I'm not so sure this will be possible in level 4 sadly - there's some documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#profiles which says even though `:not()` will allow you to use such a selector, it won't work in a CSS stylesheet because of performance reasons.

Comment: @Nico: If you're already using jQuery, you probably have nothing to worry about, particularly if you're using HTML5 and/or JS or a server-side language to validate.

Comment: I created a plugin for live form validation. You can see the last week's version at http://valideight.tk/ Documentation is not even started, yet, but it will be soon. And this way you can only submit a form when is `OK`. (And the server will validate it again, too, but it is a nicer user experience)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can reverse the logic like this. Make every link green (if that is possible in your site) and make the specific links red again.

```
a {
    color: green; 
}

a.redlink,
.redlink a {
  color: red;
}
```

Of course it depends on the structure and complexity of your site and the existance of other styling that might collide with this, but I would prefer a CSS-only solution like this over JQuery if it is reasonably possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it is not an optimized solution for me... Please see [what I just replied here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071084#comment29898486_20071138)

Comment: I see, but as @BoltClock, I don't see another pure CSS solution, so I'll guess you will have to go for a Javascript/jQuery solution.

Comment: Which is exactly what I needed on the field. But I wanted a more abstract solution for the sake of knowledge ;) Cheers!