# nesting inside css :not() selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to have nested values inside the :not selector? For eg:

```
:not(div > div)
```

Whenever I tried it, it does not seem to work. 
Perhaps you need to use it another way which I have not figured out?
So far, in all the examples I see, you can only use one value inside this selector.

Comment: `div > div div` should be the case what you are looking for.. right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`:not()` only accepts one simple selector at a time; this is mentioned in the [Selectors 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

The simple selectors in your example would be the two `div` tokens that you have. Other simple selectors include class selectors, ID selectors, attribute selectors and pseudo-classes. It does not accept more than one simple selector, nor does it accept combinators like `>` or space.

Depending on which elements you're trying to select exactly, there may not be a way to exclude `div > div`:

- If you only want to select elements that are children of a `div`, that are themselves not `div`, use this instead:

  ```
  div > :not(div)
  ```
- If you only want to select `div` elements whose parent element is not a `div`, use this instead:

  ```
  :not(div) > div
  ```

If you want to use this negation by itself, selecting *all* other elements, then there isn't a way using just a selector.

The only other viable workaround in CSS that I can think of is to apply styles to the elements you want without the `:not()` expression, then undo them for `div > div`. This works for any set of elements you're trying to target; the disadvantage is that not all properties can be easily reset.

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, which does support `:not(div > div)` [unlike the CSS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css), you can place the selector in a script and, for instance, have jQuery apply a class name to those elements then target that class in your CSS.

Comment: If one could live with a comma in their selector, `:not(div), :not(div) > div` might work to select everything that doesn't match `div > div`.

Comment: @cHao: That seems so obvious to me now, I really have no idea how I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should work now thanks to [Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/) which allows :not() to take a list of complex selectors.

You can now also nest :not()... like :not(:not()) which wasn't allowed in Selectors Level 3. Not sure why you'd want to do that but you can.