# How to use not selector to ignore specific ul li element from css?

Tags: css

How to use not selector to ignore specific ul li element from css?

```
<ul class="list">
 <li></li>
 <li>
   <ul>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
   <ul class="innerli">
     <li></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried with below code but not working

```
.list li:not(.innerli li){padding-left:10px;width: 500px;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nesting inside css :not() selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770960/nesting-inside-css-not-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

`.list ul:not(.inner) li` is the selector you are looking for I believe.

in `.list` look for all `ul`s which are not having class `.inner` and from those take all list.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to check by `ul:not(selector)` as below snippet.

```css
.list ul:not(.innerli) li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Outer</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Inner</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="innerli">
      <li>Inner</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Update:** If you wish to select both `<li>Outer</li>` as well then you have to go for multi-lines as below.

```css
/*.list ul:not(.innerli) li {
  color: red;
}*/

ul:not(.innerli) li {
  color: red;
}

ul.innerli li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Outer</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Inner</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="innerli">
      <li>Inner</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it is not working for <ul class="list">  <li>Outer</li> also :(

Comment: @BhumiShah am not sure it is possible or not!