# css select everything, but ignore specific parent and all its children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need something like this:

`html.select_everything :not(#ignore-me):not(#ignore-me *)`

The above doesn't work because I can't use both the `#ignore-me` and the `*` in the same `:not`. Is there a plain css solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

An approach that will reliably work is to override the style:

```css
.select_everything, .select_everything * {
   color:red; border:solid 1px silver;padding:2px;
}

.select_everything #ignore-me, .select_everything #ignore-me * {
  color:black;border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_everything">
  top level <div>under top level</div>
  <div id="ignore-me">not this <div>or this</div></div>
</div>
```

What you're trying to do is not supported. [MDN - :not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) says using `,` in `:not` in only supported in Safari:

> The ability to list more than one selector is experimental and not yet widely supported.

Further, `:not` is not meant for nested selectors like `a *`, see [nesting inside css :not() selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21771020/7586)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you

```
 .select_everything :not(#ignore-me,#ignore-me *) {
           //your css here
        }
```