# How to exclude a particular class in css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here's my css:

```
.single-post .container {
    width: 60%;
}

not(.single-post) .container{
            min-width:92%;
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is:
I want the container width to be 60% on single post pages and 92% on every other page. So, I am trying to exclude *.single-post* class from 2nd line of code by using *not(.single-post)* but it's not working.

However, First line of code is working fine.

Comment: Is the `.single-post` class on the `.container` element, or on a parent element?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the general case first and the more specific later. The order of declarations matters (cascading). Run the following sample to check it out.

```css
.container{
    width:92%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.single-post .container {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- normal page -->
<div>
  <div class="container">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!-- single post post page -->
<div class="single-post">
  <div class="container">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah you beat me to it. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

```
:not(.single-post) .container{
        min-width:92%;
}
```

`:` should be added.

Secondly, you may need to add `!important` after `92%`

so final code will be

```
:not(.single-post) .container{
        min-width:92% !important;
}
```

Comment: now single post pages also have 92% width in the container. So, it did not exclude .single-post class.

Comment: Can you share live url so i can see ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't use :not() on nested classes: [nesting inside css :not() selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770960/nesting-inside-css-not-selectors)

You could try using `!important` on single posts?

```
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 92%;
}

.single-post .container {
  width: 60% !important;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmgawnu8/1/

Note that you'll have to use the same CSS reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `.single-post` class is on the `body` element or another parent element, you could just write the following:

```css
.container {
  width: 92%;
}
.single-post .container {
  width: 60%;
}
```

This will set the width of the `.container` element to `92%` on all pages—except when it's on the `.single-post` page, where it will be set to `60%` because that ruleset is defined later in the cascade and is more specific than the previous ruleset.