# CSS not selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My HTML is generated by wordpress.

```
<div class="header-main">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://wp-themes.com/" rel="home">Theme Preview</a></h1>

            <div class="search-toggle active">
                <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text">Search</a>
            </div>

            <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
                <h1 class="menu-toggle">Primary Menu</h1>
                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
                <div class="nav-menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://wp-themes.com/?page_id=2">About</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-46 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://wp-themes.com/?page_id=46">Parent Page</a><ul class="children"><li class="page_item page-item-49"><a href="http://wp-themes.com/?page_id=49">Sub-page</a></li></ul></li></ul></div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

I want to hide all elements but ones with `.page-item-2` so I use:

```
.header-main .nav-menu li:not(.page-item-2) {
    display:none;
}
```

This works, but i also want to exclude `.page-item-46` from the selector:

```
.header-main .nav-menu li:not(.page-item-2) :not(.page-item-46) {
    display:none;
}
```

That doesn't work though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The element `.page-item-46` is not a descendant, therefore you would remove the space between the `:not` pseudo classes:

```
.header-main .nav-menu li:not(.page-item-2) :not(.page-item-46) {
                            /* remove this ^  */
    display:none;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaQ26/)

---

For a more basic example, consider the following:

```
<ul>
    <li class="one">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Using the following would exclude `.one`/`.two` from the selection: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkUy2/)

```
ul li:not(.one):not(.two) {
    color:red;
}
```

---

The following doesn't: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkUy2/1/)

```
ul li:not(.one) :not(.two) {
    color:red;
}
```

---

Neither does this: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkUy2/2/)

```
ul li:not(.one,.two) {
    color:red;
}
```

---

This doesn't work either because it essentially selects all elements because both selectors are not mutually exclusive. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkUy2/3/)

```
ul li:not(.one),
ul li:not(.two) {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, i see where i was wrong. I think this will work on my website. Let me test it

Comment: If you use jQuery and are wondering why `:not(.one,.two)` doesn't work here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 3):

Though you got your answer, just saying that you can also do like this if you care about older browsers:

```
.header-main .nav-menu li.page-item-2, .header-main .nav-menu li.page-item-46 {
    display: list-item;
}
.header-main .nav-menu li {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great idea. can't believe i didn't think of it!

Answer (score -1):

use this CSS

```
.header-main .nav-menu li:not(.page-item-2),.header-main .nav-menu li:not(.page-item-46) {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: That hides each of them, because 2 is not 46, and 46 is not 2. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/B6mv4/2/