# Select the first element of several sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an awkward problem, due to inheriting a shedload of really, really badly formatted HTML.

Basically I have some table rows like this:

```
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="even">...</tr>
<tr class="even">...</tr>
<tr class="even">...</tr>
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
```

And what I need is a jQuery selector that will give me the first element of each block of classes. Is that clear enough? I'm not sure how else to explain it.

So in the example case I would want rows 1, 4, and 7.

Ive done this so far by selecting every nth child, but Ive now realised this wont work as there wont always be the same number of rows in each block of classes.

Any help you guys can give it appreciated, as always :)

Cheers!

Comment: For the first two, you can use `querySelector` which returns the first Node in a NodeList. For the next block, I'm not 100% sure lemme think about it for a minute.

Comment: is it possible that for example the first **odd** block exists out of 3 elements, the first **even** out of 2 and the last **odd¨** out of 4?

Comment: @VDesign for an algorithm like this, you don't want to think static patterns.

Comment: @RUJordan I am just wondering if **odd** blocks consist out of the same amount of childs or not

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll need to employ some strategic use of `:not()` and adjacent sibling selectors:

```
$('tr.odd:first-child, tr.even:first-child, tr:not(.odd) + tr.odd, tr:not(.even) + tr.even')
```

The `tr:not(...) + tr...` bits select any `tr` element that's directly preceded by a `tr` that does not have the same class name. You can't do this dynamically (e.g. with some sort of wildcard), but it's entirely possible if you specify each class name separately. This will ensure you only select the first element in each contiguous group.

The reason the `:first-child` pseudo is required is simply because `+` won't match the first child, since it implies a relationship between an element *and* its preceding sibling. Note that `:first-child` accounts for the *very first* `tr` only. You could replace `tr.odd:first-child, tr.even:first-child` with simply `tr:first-child` if every `tr` element will have exactly one of either class name, but I specify them anyway for clarity's sake.

Last but not least, this doubles as a valid CSS selector, so you can use it in a stylesheet as well if you like.

Comment: Spot on! Really nice solution.

Comment: it's a pity that I've just found this solution but you had posted this 1 minute before.

Comment: @boltclock what the last two selector will select "tr:not(.odd) + tr.odd, tr:not(.even) + tr.even'" ?

Comment: @SivaRajini a sequence of a not-odd and an odd + the opposite. Really smart one, gj BoltClock

Comment: @SivaRajini: I updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks.please clear my doubt "tr:not(.odd) + tr.odd" how this selector will select another odd cluster first element ?

Comment: why didn't you simply use `tr.even + tr.odd` instead of `tr:not(.odd) + tr.odd` ..? both are same right..?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: I could, but I wanted to highlight the fact that using `:not()` simply means the element must come after an element that does not have the same class. If the question had more than two class names to work with, it'd be far better to use `:not()`. Listing the different class names would require you to repeat it once for every other class name.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('tr.odd:not(.odd+.odd),tr.even:not(.even+.even)')
```

This just takes any `.odd` element which isn't following another `.odd`, and any `.even` element which isn't following another `.even` element.

Comment: This answer is also correct. It shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: I've never used `:not()` in this manner, it's absolutely a new usage to me.

Comment: @King King: It's a non-standard syntax invented by jQuery. The question *is* about using jQuery to select elements though, so the answer isn't wrong *per se*. But a purist might prefer a valid CSS selector for various reasons if it is in fact possible with a CSS selector. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the info, maybe that's why it's so new to me.

Comment: In CSS, `:not` only takes a *simple selector* -- a single class name, id, pseudo-class, or possibly an attribute selector (i forget).  If you're using jQuery-specific stuff, it'd be better to split that off.  Maybe something like `$('tr.even, tr.odd').not('.even + .even, .odd + .odd')`, which would avoid the odd selector syntax altogether.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var lastGroup = ''
    $('.groups tr').each(function() {
        if(lastGroup != this.className) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            lastGroup = this.className;
        }
    });
});
```

explanation: loop through all the TR and verify if the class name (this.className) is equal to lastGroup. if not equal, we have a new group (first element of the group). if equal, ignore and continue. this will work with any class name used.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bq7zB/

Comment: Please add an explanation to this answer so the OP can learn!

Answer (score -2):

Loop through and check if the current element matches the last one, otherwise it's the first of its set:

```
var lastClass = false;
$('tr.odd, tr.even').each({ function() {
    lastClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if($(this).attr('class') != lastClass){
        // Do your conditional stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('tr.odd tr.even')` selects nothing in this case.

Comment: `Try` is not a good answer explanation. Make sure you explain line by line what your answer does, or it will most likely be downvoted

Comment: don't forget to set `lastClass` inside the loop otherwise the if condition will always be true

Answer (score -5):

```
  var prevClass = '';
  $('tr').each(function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if (prevClass === thisClass) {
     //do nothing?   
    } else {
    //push in array? do something to the row?   
    }
 });
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. Code dumps are not good answers!!