# Multiple classes inside :not()

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use the `:not()` property to exclude a pair of classes from a rule, e.g.:

```
*:not(.class1, class2) { display: none; }
```

However, it looks like the `not()` property doesn't support comma separated classes, as show in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt9LR/).

HTML:

```
<div class='one'>
  foo
</div>
<div class='two'>
  foo
</div>
<div class='three'>
  foo
</div>
<div class='four'>
  foo
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: #CBA;
}

div:not(.one) {
  background-color: #ABC;
}

div:not(.one, .three) {
  color: #F00;
}
```

The first and second rules get applied, but the third doesn't.

I can't do `*:not(.class1), *:not(.class2)` because any element which has `class2` will be selected by `*:not(.class1)` and vice versa.

I don't want to do

```
* { display: none;}
.class1, .class2 { display: inline; }
```

because not all `.class1` and `.class2` elements have the same original display property, and I want them to retain it.

How can I exclude multiple classes from a rule, either with the `not()` property or otherwise?

Comment: as you noticed , coma is not yet properly implemented , so do it this way: `*:not(.class1):not(.class2)` and so  on

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can use:

```
div:not(.one):not(.three) {
    color: #F00;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt9LR/2/)

Comment: I tried that for my project but it makes the rule too specific and it overrides most of my other rules.

Comment: how about `not(.one, .three)`? seems to work for me

Comment: @Sean - Are you using jQuery instead of plain CSS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css

Comment: @Sphinxxx I cannot remember it exactly. but a simple test should be able to verify it. Thanks for pointing out the difference between jquery and css on selector. It is useful for whoever reads it.

Comment: @Diansheng not(.one, .three) seem not to work in firefox and chrome, but somehow it is documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: According to the page provided by @yonexbat, i came to realize two things.
1. `not(.one, .three) is not well supported
2.  the two expression are not equivalent, one is not(a or b), the other is (not a)&(not b)