# CSS selector for not having classes

Tags: css

I am using selector to select all elements not having one class:

```
.list th:not(.foo) {
  /* some rules */
}
```

How can I apply this to more than one class?

```
.list th:not(.foo), .list th:not(.bar) {
  /* some rules */
}
```

The CSS above will not of course do that, I need something like this pseudo:

```
.list th:not(.foo and .bar)
```

Is it possible in CSS and how?

Comment: 4 votes for this question ? first of all it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684160/can-i-have-multiple-not-selectors second of all it's a question to which the answer can be found veeeery easily on google or even here on stackoverflow .

Comment: And? I was searching a lot and nothing has been found

Comment: my question was not about multiple not selectors, that is the answer, which I didn't know

Comment: here on SO are thousands of duplicate questions with 100 and more votes... whats your problem, man?

Comment: :) well. you need to know how to search : " css :not multiple class "  something like this. it's not that complicated.  another SO question that has been marked as duplicate of the one i gave you earlier : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266518/multiple-classes-inside-not   ....... i don't have a problem . i am just saying that posting a question that has been asked so many times and which is sooo easy to find the answer to , should be avoided and surely should not be awarded upvotes

Comment: ok, but I can't upvote it :-) and who upvoted, I don't think so, they will read these comments

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use as many `:not()` selectors as you like.

```
:not(.foo):not(.bar)
```

Answer (score 2):

With upcoming CSS4 selectors you can use a syntax like:

```
:not(.class1, .class2, .class3)
```

and so on. But browser support isn't good so far. To be able to use it today, you can use [cssnext](http://cssnext.io/) for example.

Comment: Is there a reference for CSS4?

Answer (score 1):

```
.list th:not[class*="class"] { }
```

It will work with all classes, like class1, class2 etc.

Comment: the names of classes are just examples, so how about totally different class names?

Comment: no, its not working, not with `class1` and `class2`, also you can't apply it to classes with totally different names like, f.e `my_class` and `your_house`.

Comment: .list th:not[class^="class"] { }

Comment: Would be: `list .th:not([class^="class"])`

Answer (score 0):

Use comma to separate class name can get you want

```
.list th:not(.class1, .class2)
```