# Web scraping a p tag without a class using Bs4 and Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape this ->

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXI1f.jpg)

The HTML has a div tag with a class. in this div tag there is another div tag and there is another p tag with no class. My goal is to specifically get that lone p tag without the class and get the text data from it.

So far this is my code ->

I did not include some imports and other parts of my code.

```
html = driver.page_source
time.sleep(.1)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
time.sleep(.1)


Class_Details = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"row-fluid data_row primary-row class-info class-not-checked"})

for class_detail in Class_Details:
Class_status = class_detail.find_all("div", {"class":"statusColumn"}) 
Status = Class_status[0].text

class_date = class_detail.find_all("p",{"class":"hide-above-small beforeCollapseShow"})
class_time = class_date[0].text 

The 4 lines above can be ignored they work and accomplish their tasks, the lines below however do not and is what I am asking.

cla = class_detail.find_all("p",{"class":"timeColumn"})
print(cla)

The Output of print(cla) is 
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

The good thing is that there are 7 empty lists which do coincide with the websites so it definitely is counting/ sensing the part I am scraping however I need the output to be text.

I hope I have been clear in my question and thank you for your time.

Comment: the url would help in case you don't need selenium at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **p** tag without class use a *CSS-selector* for `p` combined with the negation *pseudo-class* [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

Here, the CSS-selector could be `.timeColumn p:not([class])`:

```
# select_one to get first one
p_no_class = class_detail.select_one(".timeColumn p:not([class])").text
print(p_no_class)

# select to get all
all_p_no_class = class_detail.select(".timeColumn p:not([class])")
for p in all_p_no_class:
    print(p.text)
```

See also [CSS selector for not having classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789757/css-selector-for-not-having-classes#39789899).

Answer (score 2):

The reason your output is not printing is because you are trying to print an element, not element text. You should change your code to the following:

```
cla = class_detail.find_all("p",{"class":"timeColumn"})
for item in cla:
    print(item.text)
```

I know you are using BeautifulSoup, but I will also provide a solution using Selenium / XPath in case you do not find a BS implementation to your liking:

```
elements_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='timeColumn'/p]")

for element in elements_list:
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to extract the text **7:45am-10:50am** the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//div[@class='timeColumn']/div[contains(@id, 'days_data')]/p/a[@class='popover-bottom' and text()='F']//following::p[1]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```