# i have a lot of .not() (exclude) how can i do it just one line

Tags: jquery

i write a code for page transition but the problem is I have a lot of (link to go to in the same page) to exclude, can i do it just one line ?

```
$('a')
.not('[href="#"]')
.not('[href="#navShow"]')  // the problem
.not('[href="#navHide"]')  // the problem
.not('[href="#about"]')  // the problem

.click(function () {
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) accepts a selector, including a [selector *group*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping). So:

```
$('a').not('[href="#"], [href="#navShow"], [href="#navHide"], [href="#about"]').click(function () {
});
```

Or with `:not` instead ([CSS docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)):

```
$('a:not([href="#"]):not([href="#navShow"]):not([href="#navHide"]):not([href="#about"])').click(function () {
});
```

(Unlike `.not`, `:not` cannot accept a selector group, only a simple selector. But we can chain them within the overall selector.)

**That said**, you might consider adding a class to the `a` elements you do or do not want selected for this, and using that class (with or without `not` depending on which way you go) instead of doing this `href` check individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain multiple comma-separated attributes inside CSS's `:not` pseudo-class selector attribute list.  Shown below on a list of links with font-weight: bold for demo purposes.

While this runs in at least Chrome and Safari on desktop, I'm not sure whether it's part of the current standard, is forthcoming, or is non-standard.  For instance, I couldn't find the behavior documented on MDN, though I did find it mentioned in [a comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266518/multiple-classes-inside-not#comment73213741_24266599).

```js
$('a:not([href="#b"], [href="#c"], [href="#e"])').each(function(idx, val) {
  $(val).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#a">link a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#b">link b</a></li>
  <li><a href="#c">link c</a></li>
  <li><a href="#d">link d</a></li>
  <li><a href="#e">link e</a></li>
  <li><a href="#f">link f</a></li>
</ul>
```