# Has no class name jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Tried this but it doesn't seem to be working

```
$('this:not([class]="doneAnimated"'){

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="doneAnimated">
</div>
<div class="doneAnimated">
</div>
<div class="">
</div>
```

I want to select only div that doesn't have .doneAnimated.

Comment: use this $('div').not('.doneAnimated');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
$("div:not(.doneAnimated)")
```

Looking at the class property directly is a fragile programming practice. The class is a *list*, so checking for simple equality doesn't always work — and if it works today, it may not work after later changes.

If you need to check when your jQuery object is not formed by a selector, you can use `.not()`:

```
$(this).not(".doneAnimated")
```

If you want to just *test* the state of `this`:

```
if (!$(this).is(".doneAnimated")) {
  // do something
}
```

The `.is()` method returns `true` or `false`, while `.not()` acts like a filter on the jQuery object contents.

*edit* a comment points out that an alternative to the general-case `.is()` is `.hasClass()`:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("doneAnimated")) {
  // do something
}
```

Note that with `.hasClass()` you pass in just the class name, without a leading `.`, a mistake I've made more than once.

Comment: @jamieeason I'll add to the answer.

Comment: @jamieeason What do you mean you have to use `this`?

Comment: $(this) for single div, not all div.

Comment: There's a more specific method for that, `hasClass`

Comment: @adeneo yes you're right, and `.hasClass()` is probably faster :/

Comment: It is, `is` uses a huge regex, sizzle and some other logic to check for anything, be it an ID, class, tagname or whatever. `hasClass` uses a simple string replace to see if the class exists in the attribute. All in all, it's probably not noticeable, so it shouldn't really matter, I just mentioned it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').not('.doneAnimated');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("div:not(.doneAnimated)")` is what you are looking for.  The `:not()` function can contain any CSS selector, so insert `.doneAnimated` into it.

Comment: Note that the definition of "CSS selector", or "selector" for that matter, for the purposes of `:not()` varies depending on whether you're using CSS or jQuery. jQuery is much more permissive, CSS is much more restrictive. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

**HTML**

```
<div class="doneAnimated" style="display:none">
    has doneAnimated class 1
</div>
<div class="doneAnimated" style="display:none">
    has doneAnimated class 2
</div>
<div class="" style="display:none">
    no doneAnimated class 1
</div>
<div class="randomClass" style="display:none">
    no doneAnimated class 2
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$.each($("div:not(.doneAnimated)"), function() {
    $(this).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5vm4s4c8/)