# Select all Children except first N - CSS Selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

```
   <td>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </td>
```

I want to get all `p`s except the first 3.

I am doing it like so

```
td p:not(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3))
```

But what if I want all `p`s except first 20? Will I have to write manually like I did above?

Comment: Is that number dynamic or static? In other words are you looking for a CSS selector to be used without jQuery or with jQuery?

Comment: Note that what you currently have only works in jQuery and is not currently a valid CSS selector. See [Why is my jQuery :not() selector not working in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to use `:gt(index)` selector. This will collect matching elements with index greater than selector index

```
$('td p:gt(19)');
```

Note that index passed is zero based so for more than 20 elements use index 19

Reference:  [:gt() selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Answer (score 6):

This should work.

```css
td p:nth-child(n+5){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
        <p>7</p>
    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Thus:

```
td p:nth-child(n+21)
```

to select all p's except the first 20s.

Comment: +1 Although the question is open to jQuery answers, using standard selectors that are supported is preferred as not only can they be used in CSS, but in a script they can also leverage the browser's native selector engine instead of jQuery's proprietary engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var p = $("td p").slice(20);
```

See [jQuery.fn.slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```js
$(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
  $("table td").append("<p>" + i)
}

var p = $("td p").slice(20);
p.html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/.*/, Math.random())
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to get all **p** except the first 3 :

`$("td p:gt(2)");`

Comment: I'm so glad for you! ))