# Cant get "nth-last-child" to work

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to apply styles to all of the elements except the last one. But it doesn't work. Tried all this:

- ul li:not(ul li:nth-last-child)
- ul li:not(nth-last-child)
- ul li:not(:nth-last-child)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  border-radius: 60px;
 
}

 /* /// THIS PART IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY 
 RIGHT NOW IT REMOVES MARGIN FOR ALL THE ELEMENTS/// */
 ul li:not(ul li:nth-last-child) {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.red {background: #fc4c4f;}
.blue {background: #4fa3fc;}
.yellow {background: #ECD13F;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="red selected"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="yellow"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `:nth-last-child()` is a functional pseudo-class. It's not going to work if it doesn't know what n is supposed to be. Also, `:not()` doesn't accept combinators in CSS, unlike jQuery. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following. I assume that you dont want to apply the css to the last `ul li` element.

```
ul > li:not(:last-child){
   margin-left: 15px;
}
```

`:nth-last-child` actually expects a parameter which to look for.

[CSS3 :nth-last-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp)

Comment: This deletes margin for all elements... I have a dded the code in the question. Please help)

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to apply styles to all of the elements except the last one.

Why not use `last-child`?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.red {
  background: #fc4c4f;
}
.blue {
  background: #4fa3fc;
}
.yellow {
  background: #ECD13F;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="red selected"></li>
  <li class="blue"></li>
  <li class="yellow"></li>
</ul>
```