# Translate jQuery selector to javascript querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, selectors-api

I am trying to replicate this jQuery selector using querySelector:

```
$("*:not(#player > div)")
```

I know I can select all the elements using `querySelector('*')`, but how do I exclude the elements matching `#player > div`

Comment: You can use all CSS selectors that your browser supports in `querySelector`, so if your browser supports `:not` you're good to go.

Comment: But, `:not(#id > child)` is not supported

Comment: Which probably means you have to iterate and filter, but you generally shouldn't be using the asterisk selector at all, so there's probably a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Most jQuery selectors can be ported to `querySelector()` or CSS, but not all of them, as jQuery extends certain existing ones, along with introducing entirely non-standard selectors altogether.

In your particular case, unlike in jQuery, `:not()` only accepts a simple selector in CSS. `#player > div` is a complex selector, consisting of two simple selectors and a combinator. See this question for details:

[Why is my jQuery :not() selector not working in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css)

There is no standardized equivalent for your jQuery selector. You will have to exclude `#player > div` elements separately, by doing `document.querySelectorAll('#player > div')`, and removing elements matching that set from your original set of elements.

... [well, actually](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html), while there isn't a way to express `:not(#player > div)` in a single complex selector, because of the `>` combinator it is still possible to enumerate all the possibilities using no fewer than *four* complex selectors:

```css
:root, :not(#player) > div, #player > :not(div), :not(#player) > :not(div)
```

Here's a proof-of-concept:

```js
// The following JS + CSS should give all matching elements a 1px solid red border
$(':not(#player > div)').css('border-color', 'red');
```

```css
* { margin: 10px; }
html::before { content: 'html - Match'; }
body::before { content: 'body - Match'; }

:root, :not(#player) > div, #player > :not(div), :not(#player) > :not(div) {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>body > p - Match</p>
<div>body > div - Match</div>
<div>
  body > div:not(#player) - Match
  <p>:not(#player) > p - Match</p>
  <div>:not(#player) > div - Match</div>
</div>
<div id=player>
  body > div#player - Match
  <p>#player > p - Match</p>
  <div>
    #player > div - Non-match
    <div>#player > div:not(#player) > div - Match</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But you're still much better off either selecting those elements and removing them from your original set as described above, or just grabbing a [`matches()` polyfill](http://davidwalsh.name/element-matches-selector) and excluding elements that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove the unwanted elements.

```
var el = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'),0)
el.splice(el.indexOf(document.querySelectorAll('html')),1)
```

Comment: I don't think that this will ever work... `Array#indexOf` can only handle one element to locate in the array.