# How to get all elements which possibly have ancestors and all their ancestors are without a specified class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a part of my HTML that is similar to the one below, and I must select only the elements that do not have any ancestors with a specified class. The project I work on is pretty big and I think I should not post here all the code, I think that would be beyond the purpose of StackOverflow.

What I want is filtering the elements by all their ancestors, not only by their parents. I have tried this:

```js
// This colors two of the <span> elements instead of one. It colors the ".a > .b" <span> and this behavior seems wrong to me.
$(":not(.a) .b:not(.a)").css("color", "red");

// This call only colors the border of the ".b" <span> which, I think, is the correct behavior and should be the behavior of the call above.
$(":not(.a) > .b:not(.a)").css("border-color", "blue");
```

```css
span {
    border: 0.1rem solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <span class="b">.a > .b</span> <!-- Why does this <span> element become red? -->
  <span class="a b">.a > .a.b</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="b">.b</span>
  <span class="a b">.a.b</span>
</div>
```

I have put the code above in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silviubogan/td8kcrh0/). I have tested the two selectors using the `document.querySelectorAll` function without jQuery and the behavior is the same.

Thank you very much! `:-)`

Comment: Your question would be better if you defined what you're trying to do, instead of explaining this XY problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have updated the question. I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to select `.b` elements that

- are not `.a`, and
- *do not have any ancestors* that are `.a`?

Then this is only doable with jQuery ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css)):

```
$(".b:not(.a, .a *)")
```

If you need to do this in CSS, you can either add a class using jQuery with the above selector, or use an override:

```
.b {
  /* Style all .b elements */
}

.a .b, .a.b {
  /* Override the previous rule */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:not(.a) .b:not(.a)
```

Selects all elements with class *b*, but without class *a*, that has ***any ancestor*** without class *a*, for example, `<body>` & `<html>`.

```
:not(.a) > .b:not(.a)
```

Selects all elements with class *b*, without class *a*, that hasn't ***a direct parent*** with class *a*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It explains the behavior. Do you know how can I change the selector so that it selects all elements with class `b`, but without class `a`, that has **all the ancestors** without class `a`? Is it even possible?

Comment: @silviubogan not sure what you mean by that. looks like your 2nd version (the one the uses `>`) is what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: @BoltClock gave me the answer I was looking for, I tested his selector and it works. Thank you anyway! `:-)`