# adding an exception for querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

Say I got something like this:

```
function one() {
    var findthemall = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < findthemall.length; i++) {
        //doin' some cool stuff
    }
}
```

Now, I know I can list more than one tag in `querySelectorAll` using comma between them, but is there a simple way to make an exception for some specific classes/tags?

Like: `querySelectorAll("*, but not p and br tags")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the [method `.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) accepts CSS3 selectors, which means that you can use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to negate certain elements.

In this case, the selector `*:not(p):not(br)` would negate `br` and `p` elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll("*:not(p):not(br)");
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

```
document.querySelectorAll("*:not(p):not(br)")
```

Comment: @squint Thanks, I was testing it as you commented

Comment: Related to your first edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css The `:not()` pseudo class only accepts simple selectors.. I think `*:not(br, p)` would work in jQuery, but that's because it uses sizzle under the hood if a simple selector isn't supplied.