# Is this CSS selector incorrect .my-class *:not(input[type="text"])

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select **all elements except input of type text** inside the DOM element with class "my-class".

So, I have CSS selector like this

```
.my-class *:not(input[type="text"]) {
    // Some CSS poperties here
}
```

Is this incorrect ? It doesn't seem to work!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gpzfcn7c/  - your selector seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @Robert C: Are you testing in Safari by any chance?

Comment: @RobertC: It is not in Chrome

Comment: @BoltClock - Yeah, I had assumed OP was aware of the browser-restrictions for `not()` before trying to implement it.

Comment: @Robert C: Heh... I don't think most people are aware.

Comment: It's correct according to Selectors Level 4. But most browsers don't support it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> :not() is a CSS negation pseudo-class selector. It is a functional
>   pseudo-class selector that takes a **simple selector** as an argument, and
>   then matches one or more elements that are not represented by the
>   argument.

More info [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/not/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711731/4305494).

---

You can only use simple selectors with the :not negation pseudo-class selector.

Use the following to achieve what you want:

```
.my-class :not([type='text']) {
   //CSS properties here
}
```

Since there is no other HTML element that uses the attribute `[type="text"]` you can lose the input selector and then you'll be all set with the attribute simple selector. Also you do not need to use the * as a selector, it already matches every element.

---

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/bz7agv15/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.my-class :not([type='text'])::after {
  content: "selected";
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="radio">
  <div class="element">Div</div>
  <section>Section</section>
  <h1>H1</h1>
</div>
```

---

You may ask why it only accepts simple selectors, it's a matter of performance.

**[Fast vs Complete Selector Profiles](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#fast-profile)**

It is possible that in level four selectors they lift this restriction. It's under consideration.

Comment: The real reason :not() originally only accepted simple selectors was because they simply didn't anticipate it being used with compound or complex selectors. The performance concerns only arose when they started considering the extension, and even then those were completely unfounded - the restriction was lifted at least a year ago. The WD is woefully out of date and I have no idea when they're going to update it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.my-class input:not([type=text]), .my-class *:not(input)
```

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a
>   simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
>   argument.
>
> Negations may not be nested; :not(:not(...)) is invalid. Note also
>   that since pseudo-elements are not simple selectors, they are not a
>   valid argument to :not().

See [W3C's pseudo negation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation)

Comment: I think you quoted the wrong text. There are neither any nested :not() pseudos nor pseudo-elements in the question.