# Does [attribute != "value"] exist anywhere in CSS or have I just made it up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Having spent the last 3 years gradually improving my javascript, I am now learning the jQuery shorthand equivalents.

I have long been aware that jQuery's clever selectors can now be achieved in native Javascript using:

- `document.querySelector();`
- `document.querySelectorAll();`

However, in solving a recent problem, I used the following selector in jQuery:

```
$('div div[class!="class4"]')
```

When I tried to duplicate in Javascript what I'd successfully achieved in jQuery, I used the same selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div div[class!="class4"]')
```

But it didn't work!

Then I checked several authoritative CSS sources for the `[attribute != "value"]` and I couldn't find mention of it anywhere.

I am happy to use

```
document.querySelectorAll('div div:not(.class4)')
```

in Javascript instead.

But... what about `[attribute != "value"]` ?

Have I made it up?

And if so, why does it work in jQuery?

Comment: [Is there a CSS not equals selector?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3353968). [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Comment: "!=" is jquery ":not()" is css.

Comment: I think the dupe answers your question.

Comment: @Rounin, you can combine the `:not` with the exact-attribute selector: `div.a:not([rel="b"])` This will select all divs that has the `a` class where their rel attribute != "b". I voted for the question to reopen because I think it's not an exact dup of the other one.

Comment: So to that question - there is no specific `attribute != value` selector in css :)

Comment: There are a number of jQuery inventions that you'll be in for a rude surprise to find out don't exist in CSS. Even :not() suffers from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css

Comment: Thanks for that addition, @BoltClock. As soon as I saw the jQuery `div:not(.alpha, .beta, .gamma)` in that question, I thought: _"Wouldn't that be:_ `div:not(.alpha):not(.beta):not(.gamma)` _in CSS?"_ I'd argue that the jQuery syntax makes more sense though... if you're unfamilar with how CSS reads it, the non-spaced chaining of multiple `:nots` might suggest a logical AND operator rather than a logical OR operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"!=" is jquery ":not()" is css.

> But... what about [attribute != "value"] ?

```
jquery('[attribute != "value"]')
```

The jquery part can be modified with the css selector :not().

```
document.querySelector(':not([attribute="value"])')
```

More information about the jquery extension "!=" can be found in the documentaries:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

> Because [name!="value"] is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using [name!="value"] cannot take advantage of
>   the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $(
>   "your-pure-css-selector" ).not( "[name='value']" ) instead.

Comment: @worldofjr: Thank you, I will keep those formatting issues in mind.

Comment: Incidentally, I think this answers something else for me too: when might be a good situation to use `:not()`. For a couple of years I have avoided using `:not()` because it has always struck me as quite awkward and inelegant. But I can see now that `:not([class="not-me"])`, `:not([class^="not-"])` and `:not([class$="-me"])` are the real-world versions of the (theoretical) `([class!="not-me"])`, `([class!^="not-"])` and `([class!$="-me"])`.

Comment: Well, that comes more down to personal preference and habits. It is like using "not a is null" or "a isnot null" in various languages. By scripting in javascript and jquery people kinda know and expect to see "!=" and thus it is less confusing I assume. Then again people rather use (a != b) than !(a==b).