# javascript querySelector not working with with ':not()' option

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

Hi there are something wrong with this selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('img:not(img[src^="data"])');
```

I need to get all images which does not having a data url,

my developer console saying that

```
VM701:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'img:not(img[src^="data"])' is not a valid selector.
```

Comment: No way this is not a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css. First of all, that one is jQuery, this one vanilla JS. Second and more important, that one is about differences with jQuery/JS and CSS implementation of the selector. That one may have the solution for this in somewhere, it may serve as additional reading; but what's only needed here, is Sandeep simple explanation of *misuse* of the selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just be `...img:not([src^="data"])...`

`document.querySelectorAll('img:not([src^="data"])');`

Read more about `attribute` selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)