# css selector to exclude certain descendants and their descendants of jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a jquery object that has many levels of descendants, how do you exclude certain descendants AND their descendants? Assume there is a class (`.foo` in this case) on the top node of the elements intended for exclusion and your jquery object is the `div1` below.

EDIT: Clarification: I want to exclude ALL descendants of `.foo` and not just the immediate children.

[image: Example where we want to exclude <code>.foo</code> nodes]

```js
$('#button1').click(function() {
  var selector = '#test ' + $('#input1').val();
  var numberElements = $(selector).length;
  $('#numberElements').text(numberElements);
  var elementsAsCommaSeparatedList = _.pluck($(selector), 'id');
  $('#elementList').text(elementsAsCommaSeparatedList.join(', '));
});
```

```css
#input1 {
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#numberElements,
#elementList {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="input1">Please supply a selector... $('<input id="input1" value="div:not(.foo, .foo *)"></label>')
<button id="button1">Apply Selector</button>
<div>(default value is from @DaniP's answer)</div>
<div id="result"><span>Number of elements selected:  </span><span id="numberElements">0</span></div>
<div>
  <span>Elements selected (by id):</span>
  <span id="elementList"></span>
</div>
<div id="test">
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
      <div id="div4">
        <div id="div8"></div>
        <div id="div9"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="div5" class="foo">
        <div id="div10"></div>
        <div id="div11"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
      <div id="div6">
        <div id="div12"></div>
        <div id="div13"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="div7" class="foo">
        <div id="div14"></div>
        <div id="div15"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### JQuery

With Jquery you can use more than one argument on the `:not` selector this way will be easy to exlude the `.foo` and child elements:

```
$('div:not(.foo, .foo *)')
```

<sub>**Example Snippet**</sub>

```js
$('div:not(.foo, .foo *)').css('border-color','blue')
```

```css
div {
  padding-left:20px;
  margin:5px;
  border:thin red solid;
}
.foo {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
DIV1
  <div>
  DIV2
    <div>
    DIV4
      <div>DIV8</div>
      <div>DIV9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
    DIV5
      <div>DIV10</div>
      <div>DIV11</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  DIV3
    <div>
    DIV6
      <div>DIV12</div>
      <div>DIV13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
    DIV7
      <div>DIV14</div>
      <div>DIV15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> But CSS doesn't allow that, [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711731/2887133).

---

#### CSS

On CSS you will need to target all divs that aren't `.foo` but also overwrite again the child elements of `.foo`:

```
div:not(.foo) {
  border-color:blue;
}
div.foo * {
  border-color:red;
}
```

<sub>**Example Snippet**</sub>

```css
div {
  padding-left:20px;
  margin:5px;
  border:thin red solid;
}
.foo {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
div:not(.foo) {
  border-color:blue;
}
div.foo * {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
DIV1
  <div>
  DIV2
    <div>
    DIV4
      <div>DIV8</div>
      <div>DIV9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
    DIV5
      <div>DIV10</div>
      <div>DIV11</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  DIV3
    <div>
    DIV6
      <div>DIV12</div>
      <div>DIV13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
    DIV7
      <div>DIV14</div>
      <div>DIV15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer. I should have used some other tags, but I suppose then you'd just start it with `*` and not `div`.

Comment: Yep @johntrepreneur or just the classname whitout the tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the :not selector ?

Something like

```
div:not(.foo)
```

Comment: :not selector only excludes that level and not descendants of the :not().

Comment: div:not(.foo) > div {
  style here
}

Comment: `>` is only for immediate children. I want all descendants not just immediate children.