# CSS Selector to match input not contained in a div with specific class?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this situation

```
<div class="hidden">
  <input name="bar-foo" value="test"> 
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <input name="bar-foo-baz" value="test2">
</div>
<div class="nothidden">
  <input name="bar-foo" value="test3"> <!-- should be selected -->
</div>
<div class="nothidden">
  <input name="foo-bar-baz" value="test4"> <!-- should be selected -->
</div>
```

I need to match inputs containing word foo and bar, not contained in a div which class is 'hidden'.

```
input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"]
```

matches all the four inputs.

```
:not(.hidden) input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"]
```

in my opinion, should match inputs not contained in something with class '.hidden', but it doesn't. How do I achieve this result?

Here is it a jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/8dLbz5ws/1/

Comment: `div:not(.hidden)` rather than `:not(.hidden)` perhaps?

Comment: Specifying an element does work (verified: https://jsfiddle.net/8dLbz5ws/3/) But why this is the case, I don't know. According to MDN examples, your use-case should apply: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Since it's not using a direct descendant selector, and things like the `body` don't have the `hidden` class, the style will always be applied.

Comment: Yes, I realised this looking at @arbuthnott answer (one of those "obvious now that I see it" things)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second selector `:not(.hidden) input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"]` matches all the inputs because they are all contained in *some* element that doesn't have the hidden class (for example the `body` or another parent div).

You can fix the problem by being more specific:

```
:not(.hidden) > input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"]
```

This will filter out those with `.hidden` direct parents.

---

EDIT

Some commenters would like to know how to select all the inputs in question that are not contained in *any* `.hidden` element (not necessarily a direct parent). This is a tougher problem. The following:

```
input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"]:not(.hidden input)
```

does not seem to work, I think because `:not` only permits relatively simple selectors inside. The only way I can think of is to update all the chosen inputs and then *un-update* them when within any `.hidden` elements:

```
input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] { color: red; }
.hidden input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] { color: black; }
```

This will only work if the default settings (ie `color: black`) is uniform I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense - well spotted.

Comment: how is for `<body>
<div class="nothidden">
  <input name="foo-bar-baz" value="test4"> 
</div>
<p><input name="bar-foo" value="test3-1"></p>
</body>` ?

Comment: i think your answer is wrong because selects `input` inside `p`.

Comment: @Ehsan I've been wrong before :) But I don't see the problem. Can you explain?

Comment: @Ehsan In your example, `p` does not have `.hidden` - so it correctly selects the input inside it. However if `p` was nested inside a `div.hidden` then it would fail - is that what you mean?

Comment: @ovokuro , but it is not a `div`.problem is right here!

Comment: @Ehsan - Oh I see what you mean. I guess this answer works for the OP's question, but you are right it might need to be more specific

Comment: And if there's a number of other div in the middle? Like <div class="hidden"> <div class="anotherdiv">
  <input name="bar-foo" value="test"> </div>
</div>

Comment: @Ehsan I see what you mean. It's a different problem to select anything not inside *any* `.hidden` element. My answer just points out the general cause of error, and how to fix it for this specific case.

Comment: Tried the edit, but seem not to work in the case there are other elements in the middle (I agree it should)

Comment: @SashaGrievus, I can see that too in the fiddle. It looks like `:not` only permits fairly simple selectors in the argument. I'll try to update to something else that will work.

Comment: "The following does not seem to work, I think because `:not` only permits relatively simple selectors inside." It [doesn't work in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711731), but it [works in jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/u3e9a83o/1/), which [doesn't have that restriction](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/): "All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a)`."

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/1dd2a3sw/

```
div:not(.hidden) input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] {
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change like this:

```
div:not(.hidden) input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
div:not(.hidden) input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">
  <input name="bar-foo" value="test"> 
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <input name="bar-foo-baz" value="test2">
</div>
<div class="nothidden">
  <input name="bar-foo" value="test3"> <!-- should be selected -->
</div>
<div class="nothidden">
  <input name="foo-bar-baz" value="test4"> <!-- should be selected -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try targetting only the direct children of your classes that are not hidden, like this:

```
:not(.hidden) > input[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] { color:blue; }
```