# Selenium (via Python) errors on SOME (but not all) :not(...) CSS selectors

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Running Python 2.7.8 & Selenium 3.11.0 (with Chrome webdriver), seeing some weird behavior. tl/dr, trying to use `find_elements_by_css_selector`, and it IS respecting a selector like `p:not(.ignore)` but NOT `p:not(.ignore p)` (though they both work in the real browser.

I'm serving the following webpage for test purposes:

```
<html>
    <title>Test</title>
    <body>
        <section class="ignore">
            <p>Some content I don't want to pull.</p>
        </section>
        <p>Content I DO want to pull.</p>
        <p>More important content.</p>
        <p>Thanks for reading.</p>
        <p class="also-ignore">(We CAN successfully ignore this one tho.)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And accessing it via Selenium with the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        driver.get('http://localhost:8000/test.html')
        elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('p:not(.ignore p)')
        for e in elems:
            print e.text
    finally:
        driver.close()
```

The above throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 10, in <module>
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('p:not(.ignore p)')
  File "/Users/maiamccormick/code/seleniumtest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 605, in find_elements_by_css_selector
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/Users/maiamccormick/code/seleniumtest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 983, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/Users/maiamccormick/code/seleniumtest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/maiamccormick/code/seleniumtest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)
```

(The selector `p:not(.ignore p)` DOES work in the Chrome console.)

The above Python code runs without error (and with expected output) with the CSS selector `p:not(.also-ignore)` (i.e. ignoring the last `<p>` element in the page), so the problem does not seem to be with the `:not(...)` selector itself. I'm stumped -- anyone have thoughts?

Comment: FWIW, replicated this behavior with the Firefox webdriver as well (same selectors do/don't work using Firefox webdriver -- and all work in Firefox console).

Comment: Apart from what is working and what not do you have a question for us? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: @DebanjanB tbh I'm not actually looking for help making something WORK -- I am easily able to hack around the problem above. I'm more curious WHY the selector didn't work as I expected it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a
>   simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its
>   argument.

This means that `p:not(.ignore p)` is not supported.

Now the reason it's working in the console is because the shorthand `$` is overwritten by the page with `JQuery` which supports a different syntax.

Since Selenium rely on the CSS selector from the browser (same as `document.querySelector`) and not from JQuery, the exception in this case is to be expected.

Note that you'll get the exception in the console by either executing `document.querySelector('p:not(.ignore p)')` or `$('p:not(.ignore p)')` in a blank page (about:blank).

If you wish to use a JQuery selector, then use a JavaScript injection:

```
elms = driver.execute_script("return $('p:not(.ignore p)')")
```

Comment: See also: [Why is my jQuery :not() selector not working in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css)